# embedding dual apps with webserver

Tags: google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode

I've run into issues when running a web server in an app that is embedded using the AppView approach.

The background is that we need to run two applications in Kiosk mode (digital signage implementation).
There is a primary app and a supporting application running, the support application needs to run a local web server for configuration and control purposes.
The web server needs to be accessible from external browsers.

I have had some success embedding the app with the web server and being able to access from a browser running on the same device, but not remotely. 
These tests have only been done in desktop rather than kiosk mode.

From what I can tell the Manifest for both the embedded and host apps are correct, in that the apps run in single app mode ok.
The apps will embed using the AppView tag.
as per...  https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/appview

1 - Is it possible to embed a web server as per the above senario?
2 - Are there any additional properties needed in the manifest

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

P.S.
There are a few additional undocumented requirements for the embedding to work in Kiosk mode.
Such as listing the apps ID in the in the manifest for the container app.
i.e. you need to include  "kiosk_secondary_apps" with a list of kiosk mode apps that you want to embed.

Comment: You could embed the web server directly in the kiosk app. See https://github.com/matt-cook/kiosk/commit/32eb1040f194c30b9e325f107cb359e86b077085 for an example

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  One of the apps that needs to be embedded in the AppView tag already has a web server integrated.  This server works ok in single app mode but fails when embedded.   I suspect that the server is being blocked.  Not a great deal of info on the AppView tag so flying a little blind here.

Comment: You don't mention what platform you're testing on, but if on windows you'll need to disable the default firewall to be able to reach the web server from another computer.

Comment: The target platform is kiosk mode on ChromeOS.

Comment: It sounds like app embedding may have a bug - not creating a firewall rule to allow connections on the chrome.sockets webserver port. If you're relatively sure this is the case then perhaps create a minimal test case example and put on crbug ?